# How to use Android Support Library permission delegates?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-support-library, android-permissions

The version 27.0.0 of the Android Support Library introduces the class [`FragmentCompat.PermissionCompatDelegate`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v13/app/FragmentCompat.PermissionCompatDelegate.html). I wondered what it was exactly and how it should be used (reading the docs without any example didn't help much).

I dived a bit deeper, and discovered [`FragmentCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v13/app/FragmentCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback.html), introduced back in 24.1.0, and also noticed that these two nested interfaces have [`ActivityCompat`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.html) variants, introduced in the same Support Library versions.

Do these interfaces finally allow any class to manage permissions requests and grant results without having to do ugly hacks like are done in [most of these libraries](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/235?category=1) that often required to extend a "BaseActivity" or "BaseFragment"?

How to use them? If you answer with code, Kotlin snippets are appreciated, but Java ones are accepted too!

Comment: My library do not require you to extend `BaseActivity` or something. Just get a reference of context and you are good to request permission from anywhere. https://github.com/nabinbhandari/Android-Permissions

Comment: Can have a look on https://github.com/googlesamples/android-RuntimePermissionsBasic